# Sequence of linear maps between Banach Spaces and Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Tags: banach-spaces, linear-transformations

I have some problems proving the following :

> Let $T,T_1,T_2,\dots$ linear maps between $E,F$, two Banach spaces (on the same field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$),$B \subset E$ s.t. $\overline{Span(B)}=E$. Then we have equivalence between :
>
> 1. $T_n(b) \to T(b) ~\forall b \in B$ and $\sup_{n}\|T_n\| < \infty$,
> 2. $T_n(x) \to T(x) ~\forall x \in E$.

I have been given the hint to use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem but I do not understand how. I know that 1 implies that $T$ is continuous but I do not know if this will help.

Thank you.

Comment: Continuous is the same as bounded. In $2$, each $T_n$ is continuous, hence each $T_n$ is (pointwise) bounded i.e. there is a bounding constant $c_n$ for each $T_n$. By Banach Steinhaus theorem, the $T_n$ are uniformly bounded, so the $c_n$ get combined into one $C$.

Comment: So this prove 2 from 1 if I am correct. But what about $1 \implies 2$ ?

Comment: Isn't $2$ just continuity? And you said you knew that $1$ implied continuity. Anyway, it follows from density and uniform boundedness.

Comment: If we take $(b_m)$ s.t. $b_m \to x$, then we have $T_n(b_m) \to T_n(x)$ by continuity, and $T_n(b_m) \to T(b_m)$ by 1. But I cannot see why it implies 2.

Comment: Write $T_n(x) - T(x) = (T_n(x) - T_n(b)) + (T_n(b) - T(b)) + (T(b) - T(x))$, and use the continuity of $T$ and $T_n$, along with triangle inequality.

Comment: Of course... Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.